# MySQL Select columns messed up

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, select

Here's the problem.

First, I created a database in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE Users (User TEXT, Pass TEXT, ID TEXT, RegDate TEXT, Email TEXT, Rank TEXT);
```

I have this database now

```
+-----------+------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
| User      | Pass             | ID         | RegDate  | Email             | Rank       |
+-----------+------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
```

I imported a csv file (Users.csv) (UTF-8, PlainText) using

```
load data local infile 'Users.csv' into table Users fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
```

That file's contents is

```
arinerron,asdfasdf,USR0000001,92082015,arinesaugmail,Owner
looy,asdfasdf,USR0000002,92082015,tjesaugmail,User
mooncat39,marsisawesome,USR0000003,92082015,harveyfamilygmail,Owner
Goldy,foxythepirate777,USR0000004,92082015,goldyftwgmail,User
Reid,reidyreid,USR0000005,92082015,reidgmail,Moderator
Bo,bobobobo,USR0000006,92082015,bobogmail,Moderator
```

Its response was

```
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I ran the command

```
SELECT * from Users
```

And I got this response

```
+-----------+------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
| User      | Pass             | ID         | RegDate  | Email             | Rank       |
+-----------+------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
     |erron | asdfasdf         | USR0000001 | 92082015 | arinesaugmail     | Owner
      |     | asdfasdf         | USR0000002 | 92082015 | tjesaugmail       | User
     |cat39 | marsisawesome    | USR0000003 | 92082015 | harveyfamilygmail | Owner
      |     | foxythepirate777 | USR0000004 | 92082015 | goldyftwgmail     | User
 |Reid      | reidyreid        | USR0000005 | 92082015 | reidgmail         | Moderator
| Bo        | bobobobo         | USR0000006 | 92082015 | bobogmail         | Moderator  |
+-----------+------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
```

What is wrong with it? Why is it not formatting correctly? Also the Rank column is messed up

I retried the steps over and over with no success. I really need this solved as soon as possible. Thanks a lot!

Comment: so what exactly is it that you need to solve? I see that you are saving plain text passwords which is a huge, huge problem but I don't think that's what this post is about. Am I right?

Comment: @e4c5 Yes, this is a test database, I am going to make the passwords salted/encrypted later. I need help with the other problem though. I also see that the emails are messed up but I know how to fix it, I just need this other problem fixed first!

Comment: so what' the other problem?

Comment: @e4c5 Look on the user column. What is wrong with it? Why is it not formatting correctly? Also the Rank column is messed up

Comment: There's nothing wrong with! your data is too long to fit into one line in the mysql console so the rank column (which I suspect has extra white space at the end) is carrying on to the next line.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `user` is a reserved word, and might cause unexpected behavior, and your file contents are not `enclosed by '"'`.

Comment: @e4c5 (Sorry I'm a n00b at this) Why isn't it fixing when I resize the window really long and redo the command? I tried removing some unnessacary columns before.... It still does it. :P

Comment: @Kendall You might want to post that as an answer, because I changed that and it works now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your file has Windows CR-LF line endings, not Unix LF line endings. So the `Rank` fields all have a CR character at the end. So what's happening is that the last field is being printed as:

```
Owner<cr><spaces>|
```

The `<cr>` returns to the beginning of the same line, then it prints several spaces and the `|`. This overwrites the beginning of the `User` field.

Use

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Or use `dos2unix` to remove all the CR characters from the file before loading it.

Comment: . . How would that mess up the first field in the first line?

Comment: The CR in the last field is returning to the beginning of the line before printing the spaces and `|` at the end, so they overwrite the beginning of the first field.

Comment: I did both this and changed column called user to username, and deleted enclosed by '"', and did the lines terminated by '\r\n' suggestion, and now it works. What should I mark as answer?

Comment: There's no problem with a column named `user`, that change was unnecessary.

Comment: You also don't have the word `user` anywhere in the query, so how could it being a reserved word be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth mentioning that `user` is a keyword, and might cause unexpected behavior, and your file contents are not `enclosed by '"'`.

Posted here at the OP's request.

Comment: `USER` is a keyword, it's not a reserved word. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html. There's no `(R)` next to it.

Comment: My mistake. I looked it up quickly, but didn't notice the distinction.

Comment: He also doesn't have the word `user` in the query. So even if it were reserved, how would it be a problem? And if you misuse a reserved word you get a syntax error, not incorrect data loaded into the table.

Comment: It wasn't really the query I was concerned about, but the way the the data was imported. In any case, he made changes based on the comment, and he got the results he was hoping for. I only posted it as an answer at his request.

Comment: I think you don't really know what you're talking about. Reserved words have nothing to do with the data, they only affect parsing queries. You can use a reserved word in a query simply by enclosing it in backticks.